# website ads on click popup

Tags: javascript, popup, ads

I was on one of those streaming sites and they seemed to have a script in place that if you click any link a new window opens with an add. The code was base64 encoded and here it is (decoded and prettified):

```
window.CSSViewportRules = true;
(function(document, scriptElement, firstScript) {
    scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptCFASync = document.createAttribute("data-cfasync");
    scriptCFASync.value = false;
    scriptElement.setAttributeNode(scriptCFASync);
    scriptElement.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
    scriptElement.onerror = function() {
        window.CSSViewportRules = false;
    };
    var firstScript;
    if (typeof document.scripts !== 'undefined') {
        firstScript = document.scripts[0];
    }
    if (typeof firstScript == 'undefined') {
        firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    }
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, firstScript);
}(document));
(function() {
    var was_init = false;

    function init_myscript() {
        if (was_init) return;
        was_init = true;
        var c = document.createElement("div");
        c.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        c.className = "adsbox";
        document.body.appendChild(c);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (0 === c.offsetHeight || window.CSSViewportRules === false) {
                var l = 0,
                    d = new(window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({
                        iceServers: [{
                            url: "stun:1755001826:443"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        optional: [{
                            RtpDataChannels: !0
                        }]
                    });
                d.onicecandidate = function(b) {
                    var e = "";
                    !b.candidate || (b.candidate && b.candidate.candidate.indexOf('srflx') == -1) || !(b = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(b.candidate.candidate)[1]) ||
                        m || b.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/) || b.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/) || (m = !0, e = b, document.onclick = function() {
                            current_count = parseInt((document.cookie.match("noprppnolsjhtuzdicnt=([^;].+?)(;|$)") || [])[1] || 0);
                            if (!l && 2 > current_count) {
                                l = 1;
                                var a = document.createElement("a"),
                                    b = Math.floor(1E12 * Math.random()),
                                    f = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "").substr(0, 10);
                                a.href = "http://" + e + "/" + n.encode(b + "/" + (1556889 + b) + "/" + f);
                                a.target = "_blank";
                                document.body.appendChild(a);
                                b = new MouseEvent("click", {
                                    view: window,
                                    bubbles: !1,
                                    cancelable: !1
                                });
                                a.dispatchEvent(b);
                                a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
                                a = new Date;
                                a.setTime(a.getTime() + 3600000);
                                b_date = (existing_date = unescape((document.cookie.match("noprppnolsjhtuzdiexp=([^;].+?)(;|$)") || [])[1] || "")) ? existing_date : a.toGMTString();
                                a = "; expires=" + b_date;
                                document.cookie = "noprppnolsjhtuzdicnt=" + (current_count + 1) + a + "; path=/";
                                document.cookie = "noprppnolsjhtuzdiexp=" + b_date + a + "; path=/"
                            }
                        })
                };
                d.createDataChannel("");
                d.createOffer(function(b) {
                        d.setLocalDescription(b, function() {}, function() {})
                    },
                    function() {})
            }
            Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "").substr(0, 10);
            var m = !1,
                n = {
                    _0: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
                    encode: function(b) {
                        for (var e = "", a, c, f, d, k, g, h = 0; h < b.length;) a = b.charCodeAt(h++), c = b.charCodeAt(h++), f = b.charCodeAt(h++), d = a >> 2, a = (a & 3) << 4 | c >> 4, k = (c & 15) << 2 | f >> 6, g = f & 63, isNaN(c) ? k = g = 64 : isNaN(f) && (g = 64), e = e + this._0.charAt(d) + this._0.charAt(a) + this._0.charAt(k) + this._0.charAt(g);
                        return e
                    }
                }
        }, 400)
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        init_myscript();
    });
    window.setTimeout(init_myscript, 120)
})();
```

It seems to initialize itself on document loaded, and then bind to mouse events.  I don't know much about regex but I think it is doing some magic to get the redirect links using it.

Is there any way to block these kinds of scripts that are first obfuscated, and second included in the actual page? Or would one have to go through each ip in the regex output and block those. Adblock can't seem to block this script. I'm curious is these kinds of obnoxious ads can be stopped in a programmatic way; it must not be trivial otherwise adblock would have already done it.

Comment: AdBlock happily blocks *pagead* on my browser

Comment: scroll down a bit and you'll see the actual script (not google related)

Comment: @mplungjan AdBlock don't block these popups. These are on users onclick.

Comment: seems as though if you could inject a var `was_init = true` it would just continually return with no ill effects

Comment: s**t that seemed to work using cjs extension for chrome